# How to open Office MSG file w/o MS Office Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, viewer

How to open Office MSG file w/o MS Office Outlook? Do know any free reder? I have found one, but it is not free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help you out?

[Codeproject: MsgReader DLL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/MsgReader.aspx)

Scroll down for a full project. (TestofMsgReaderDll.zip)

Comment: Test project chrashes (Download DLL (TestOfMsgReaderDll) - 72.21 KB).

Comment: Contact the developer :)

Comment: Here's the website of them: http://msgviewer.blogspot.com

Comment: I tried `TestOfMsgReaderDll.exe` in i386-wine-devel 5.8_1,1 on FreeBSD-CURRENT, it didn't run.